# ID Token Validation in Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am very new to Azure B2C and trying to explore the options available to manage the identities in B2C. I have registered web application and also created required custom policy in B2C tenant. When I am trying to run the workflow from Azure B2C portal, I am able to redirect to registered application with IdToken and also able to view the ID token information in https://jwt.io

Below are some of the question which requires clarification

1. Suppose I have hyperlink in my web application(Asp.Net web form) which redirects the user into Azure B2C. On successful signin in Azure B2C, how to validate ,process ID Token and fetch the user information in web application. I have seen code samples related to button click event.
2. How to refresh the token in the above case.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the [MSAL library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples) on the client side.

This does all this for you.

You get back an id_token and an access token.

Only an access token can be refreshed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I couldn't find any sample code related to MSAL Asp.Net web Application.I would like implement the code in Global.asax instead of StartUp OWIN Classes. Can you please provide me some suggestion or reference articles.

Comment: All those samples use MSAL.